Absolute positioning one element in a Mui Material Grid
I'm building a web page using @mui/material/Grid.  The layout should have the following 'rows':
Some text at the top
A toolbar
Some content
The toolbar contains 4 things; the first 2 are buttons, and the other 2 are controls.  I want to show the buttons left-aligned, and then the controls right-aligned.  So:
|<--------------- section width --------------->|
| Button  Button               Control  Control |
This bit is fine.  However, the second control is a button with a drop-down menu, and when it's open the drop-down menu should cover the content below.
If I just had the Control (not in a Grid, and not with the other buttons etc) I can do this by using position: absolute for the control.  However, in the Grid layout, adding position: absolute is causing the 2 controls to overlap each other.  How can I make this work?
Here's what I have currently:
  <Grid container justifyContent={'center'} alignItems="flex-start">
    <Grid item={true} xs={12} md={8}>
      <div className="section-text">
        <p>Some text here...</p>
      </div>
      <Grid container justifyContent={'center'} alignItems="flex-start">
        <Grid item={true} xs={12} md={6}>
          <div className="buttons">
            <div className="button">
                <Button>Button Name</Button>
            </div>
            <div className="button">
                <Button>Button Name</Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item={true} xs={12} md={6}>
          <div className="controls">
            <SortControl className="control-sort" />
            <FilterControl className="control-filter" />
          </div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container justifyContent={'center'} alignItems="flex-start">
        Page Contents go here...
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>

The corresponding css is:
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.controls {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.control-filter {
  z-index: 10;
}

When it's like this, everything is positioned correctly, apart from the page content, which is pushed down below the dropdown menu.
If I add position: absolute; to the control-filter class, the page content moves up, with the dropdown overlapping it, but the sort control is now hidden underneath the filter control.
How do I achieve this?
